# Error when creating DynamoDB Hive table from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, amazon-dynamodb, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

In my attempts to store a DataFrame into a DynamoDB table, I tried creating a DynamoDB Hive table. I'm using Python/Pyspark and I'm starting my Spark app with `--jars /usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hive.jar`.

```
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

sqlContext.sql('CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE ddb (col1 string) \
    STORED BY "org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler" \
    TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "table1", "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "col1:col1")')
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
INFO DDLTask: Use StorageHandler-supplied org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBSerDe for table default.ddb
ERROR DDLTask: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe.initSerdeParams(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/lazy/LazySimpleSerDe$SerDeParameters;
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBSerDe.initialize(DynamoDBSerDe.java:51)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:527)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:391)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:276)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:258)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:605)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:694)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4135)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1653)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1195)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1049)
....
```

I'm using the EMR 4.3 configuration (all applications). It could be related to this [Hive issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12406).

Any ways to circumvent this? Thanx!

Comment: The problem is also present on EMR 4.2 (Spark 1.5.2).

Comment: Further diagnostics: the problem is also on EMR 4.1, EMR 4.4 (unannounced release) also. Not present on EMR 4.0. But there are other issues with that release.